# ios upgrade from iOS 6 to iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

Maybe you can share me link or tell me about datas on iPhone after upgrade to iOS 7?

I meen next:

I have app, which save data in .plist and send it ti iCloud (`ubiquity container`). So when we upgrade our device - can iOS delete app's plist or deleted datas in `ubiquity container`?

Comment: Why would you like to delete your data in iCloud when upgrading the OS?

Comment: @NikosM. I mean, if iOS itself can remove my file from ubiquity container or .plist from my app, when user upgrade from iOS 6 to iOS 7?

Comment: Since you can have your data backed up to the iCloud when updating I would assume that it isn't deleted when updating from `iOS6` to `iOS7`. Also anything that happens on your iCloud space would have to be authorized by yourself before hand so if it said "Do you want to delete your data?" just say no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment: No application data (in the app or stored in iCloud) will be deleted or modified during an iOS upgrade. Apps run sandboxed and upgrade procedures do not touch the app sandbox.